# Not receiving query request when using GET form

Tags: node.js, websocket

I am using WebSockets to try to get a URL submitted from an html form;

```
// in html
<form method="GET">
   <input name="id">
// on the server
ws.on('connection', (socket, req) => {
    console.log(req.url); // this is what i want
    console.log('connection');
});
```

When submitting the form, the browser's URL changes to '?id=...', however i get a request only containing a single slash '/'. I am wondering if this is an issue with the way the WebSocket is setup, However changing the client's websocket URL makes it work.

```
new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3000/?id=test'); // this works as expected
```

The server code is setup like this:

```
const server = http.createServer();
const ws = new WebSocket.Server({server});

ws.on('connection', (socket, req) => {
    console.log(req.url); // here the console only prints out a '/' when the form is submitted
    console.log('connection');
});

server.listen(port);
```

I then removed the WebSocket, and changed the HTTP to this `http.createServer((req)=>{console.log(req.url);});`
This correctly receives the request, however when using WebSockets it never seems to work. Could this be because I am locally hosting the server?

Is it possible, and if so how can I retrieve the URL while using WebSockets with http?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so apparently you have to enter the search parameters into the websocket URL itself (I didn't know that).
So on the client it becomes `new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.hostname + ':3000/' + window.location.search);`

For now this works fine for my use case.